# Lookahead RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string in JavaScript which is a basic oData batch request:

```
--batchfull
Content-Type:  multipart/mixed; boundary=batchitems

--batchitems
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

MERGE /WcfDataService1.svc/Orders(1) HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;type=entry

{"OID":"2340324","PID":"234234"}

--batchitems
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST /WcfDataService1.svc/Users HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;type=entry

{"PID":"234234","Name":"User1"}

--batchitems--
--batchfull--
```

Each item which makes up the batch is as follows:

```
--batchitems
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST /WcfDataService1.svc/Users HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;type=entry

{"PID":"234234","Name":"User1"}
// new line here too
```

I am trying to write a regex to extract each of these batch items, but I can't get it working. So far I have:

```
/--batchitems$.*?(?=--batchitems)/ig
```

But, it does not work.

1) I tried building it up so at first I had /--batchitems$/ig. Without the dollar, it worked, with it, it did not work (nothing was matched).

Any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: I'd be tempted just to do `str.split(/--batchitems[\r\n]+/)` and then throw away the first and last entries in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `[\s\S]*?` intstead of `.*`, since js won't support DOTALL modifier `s` .

```
/--batchitems\n([\s\S]*?)(?=--batchitems)/ig
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vS2lU5/1)

Comment: This looks good! Two questions, why did you replace the `$` with `\n`, and the DOTALL being `.*`? I thought it did support this?

Comment: `\n([\s\S]*?)` should not capture the newline character where `$([\s\S]*?)` should capture `\n` char.